# Getting a value from a session in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've saved a session in a database and it's got more then one value in it. So what I'm trying to get the qty value from the session.

My code to save the session

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $cart_details = Cart::content();

    $cart_session_test = Session::put('cart_session_test', $cart_details);

    $cart_data_test = Session::get('cart_session_test');

    $cart_test = [
        'data' => json_encode($cart_data_test),
    ];

    $customer_id = auth()->guard('customer_admin')->user()->id;

    $carts_tbl_test = DB::table('cart_session')->where(['customer_id' => $customer_id])->first();

    if(isset($carts_tbl_test))
    {
        DB::table('cart_session')->where(['customer_id' => $customer_id])->update($cart_test);
    }else{
        $cart_test['customer_id'] =   $customer_id;
        DB::table('cart_session')->insert($cart_test);
    }

    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    return redirect()->route('login')->with('success', 'You`ve been successfully logged out');
}
```

When I hit $cart_test and I echo it out I get

> Array
>       (
>           [data] => {"18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf":{"rowId":"18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf","id":"8","name":"Product 8","qty":"2","price":80,"image":"[\"hot-dog.jpg\"]","options":[],"tax":16.8,"subtotal":160}}
>       )

so then in my login function I did this

```
$customer_id = auth()->guard('customer_admin')->user()->id;

$carts_tbl = DB::table('cart_session')->where(['customer_id' => $customer_id])->first();

if(isset($carts_tbl))
{
    $cart_data = json_decode($carts_tbl->data);
    Session::put('cart_session_test', $cart_data);
}

$show_session = Session::get('cart_session_test');

echo "<PRE>";
print_r($show_session->qty);
die();
```

and I got this error

> ErrorException in CustomersController.php line 81:
>   Undefined property: stdClass::$qty

Line 81 is

```
print_r($show_session->qty);
```

Comment: dump the `$show_session` variable.

Comment: When I `dd($show_session)` I get `{#410 ▼
  +"18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf": {#411 ▼
    +"rowId": "18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf"
    +"id": "8"
    +"name": "Product 8"
    +"qty": "2"
    +"price": 80
    +"image": "["hot-dog.jpg"]"
    +"options": []
    +"tax": 16.8
    +"subtotal": 160
  }
}`

Comment: See, In session you are storing `qty` inside another array of `18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf`.

Comment: And I think, its not array its json.

Comment: I do save it as a json but then when I want to get the data I use `json_decode`

Comment: You have saved the data inside `18d6934483b994fb9943b43b7d7646bf` key.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use json encode or decode. As I prefer using the laravel helpers, `Session::` becomes `session()->`

```
$customer_id = auth()->guard('customer_admin')->user()->id;

$carts_tbl = DB::table('cart_session')->where(['customer_id' => $customer_id])->first();

if($carts_tbl->count() == 1)
{
    session()->put('cart_session_test', $carts_tbl->data);
}

$show_session = session()->get('cart_session_test');

dd($show_session['qty']);
```

The reason is you lose object information when you *json-ize* it. You can even access properties directly `session()->get('cart_session_test')['qty']`

In your CartSession model add this: `$casts = ['data' => 'object']` or `$casts = ['data' => 'array']` depending on what you want. In your case 'array' should do as 'qty' seems an array item for the 'data' field. As such you don't need to worry about type juggling. Laravel will take care of that.

Better would be to make a `cart_items` table and save whatever is in the data field in there in a OneToMany relationship with `cart_session` (should be `cart_sessions` but it's ok). It will safe you a lot of trouble later on and simplify building your app. Been there, done that.

Comment: I keep getting `Call to undefined method stdClass::count()` this error

Answer (score 1):

In your `logout` controller you are flushing the session. So when you flush the session it remove the data from the database.

So when you access the data from `login`, it will give you nothing.

Change your `login` function like this :

```
$customer_id = auth()->guard('customer_admin')->user()->id;

$carts_tbl = DB::table('cart_session')->where(['customer_id' => $customer_id])->first();

if($carts_tbl)
{
    $cart_data = json_decode($carts_tbl->data);
    Session::put('cart_session_test', $cart_data);
    $show_session = Session::get('cart_session_test');

    echo "<PRE>";
    print_r($show_session->qty);
    die();
}
```

Comment: I get this error `ErrorException in CustomersController.php line 73:
                            Undefined property: stdClass::$qty` line 73 is `print_r($show_session->qty);`

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: I have. Maybe I'm just not seeing it or getting it. Also when I flush the session the data is still in the database.